# Problem with weigts in survey analysis of GSS cross-sectional data

Tags: survey, population, weights, cross-section, survey-weights

I have a dataset made from https://gss.norc.org/get-the-data

There is a description from the codebook how to use weights:

```
cluster VPSU;
strata VSTRAT;
weight WTSSPS /* For years before 2021, use WTSSALL or WTSSNR */;
```

I'm going to use WTSSALL with all the data prior 2021, so I selected all years which have this variables: VPSU,VSTRAT and WTSSPS into my dataset gss and then selected few other variables for analysis.

```
> head(gss)

# A tibble: 6 × 10
    uid class         health      age  vpsu vstrat wtssall  year race  age_group
  <int> <fct>         <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>    
1  4602 working class excellent    38     1   7001   1.40   1975 White 25-44    
2  4603 middle class  excellent    20     1   7001   1.40   1975 White 18-24    
3  4604 working class fair         61     1   7001   0.466  1975 White 45-64    
4  4605 middle class  excellent    19     1   7001   0.932  1975 White 18-24    
5  4606 middle class  good         28     1   7001   1.40   1975 White 25-44    
6  4607 middle class  excellent    28     1   7002   0.932  1975 White 25-44
```

creating a survey design

```
gss_a_design <-svydesign(id = ~vpsu, 
                           strata = ~vstrat, 
                           data = subset(gss, 
                                         !is.na(class) & 
                                         class!="no class" & 
                                         !is.na(health)), 
                           weights = ~wtssall, 
                           nest = TRUE)
```

> summary(gss_a_design)

```
Stratified 1 - level Cluster Sampling design (with replacement)
With (4153) clusters.
svydesign(id = ~vpsu, strata = ~vstrat, data = subset(gss, !is.na(class) & 
    class != "no class" & !is.na(health)), weights = ~wtssall, 
    nest = TRUE)
Probabilities:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.1144  0.9103  0.9897  1.2086  1.8179  2.5522 
Stratum Sizes: 
           1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009 1010 1011 1012 1013 1014 1015 1016 1017 1018 1019
```

I can't really tell if this is correct at all, but when I'm trying to get basic statistics out of this design, there is a problem

```
svyby(~health, ~class, gss_a_design, svymean, deff=TRUE, ci=TRUE, vartype="ci")
                      class healthexcellent healthgood healthfair healthpoor ci_l.healthexcellent
lower class     lower class       0.1554207  0.3593957  0.3069389 0.17824468            0.1379645
working class working class       0.2580988  0.4909776  0.2021652 0.04875846            0.2508581
middle class   middle class       0.3583512  0.4477918  0.1543764 0.03948070            0.3501909
upper class     upper class       0.4787682  0.3578701  0.1250240 0.03833767            0.4486061
              ci_l.healthgood ci_l.healthfair ci_l.healthpoor ci_u.healthexcellent ci_u.healthgood
lower class         0.3368265       0.2853632      0.16147377            0.1728769       0.3819650
working class       0.4828618       0.1956606      0.04537990            0.2653394       0.4990935
middle class        0.4396152       0.1484209      0.03639970            0.3665115       0.4559683
upper class         0.3293159       0.1055183      0.02731352            0.5089303       0.3864243
              ci_u.healthfair ci_u.healthpoor DEff.healthexcellent DEff.healthgood DEff.healthfair
lower class         0.3285147      0.19501558                   NA              NA              NA
working class       0.2086697      0.05213701             131.1441        126.2381        125.6425
middle class        0.1603318      0.04256171             158.8733        148.3204        149.0428
upper class         0.1445298      0.04936182                   NA              NA              NA
              DEff.healthpoor
lower class                NA
working class         117.881
middle class          137.321
upper class                NA
Warning messages:
1: In svymean.survey.design2(data, design[byfactor %in% byfactor[i],  :
  Sample size greater than population size: are weights correctly scaled?
2: In svymean.survey.design2(data, design[byfactor %in% byfactor[i],  :
  Sample size greater than population size: are weights correctly scaled?
```

In the lower and upper classes I can't see the design effect difference and this warnings also confusing. Does this mean that the weights are incorrectly applied and my result will be biased and inference will be wrong as well? What is the solution for this problem and how to analyze this survey correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i remember correctly, `nrow(gss) == sum( gss$wtssall )` instead of summing to the entire noninstitutionalized population of us adults (258M in 2020)?  as a simple workaround to eliminate both the warning and the `NA`, maybe before the `svydesign()` call, just inflate the weights column so it actually sums to the number of individuals it actually represents rather than the number of survey respondents..

```
gss[ , 'wtssall_scaled' ] <- gss[ , 'wtssall' ] * 258000000 / nrow( gss )
```

and then use `weights = ~ wtssall_scaled` as your weight rather than `~ wtssall` when making the survey design?

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is working now!